# appendChild only works first time

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I want to repeatedly append the same stuff to an element via a button and event handler on the same page.

The problem I'm encountering is that it only works first time. It does exactly what I want the first time, then fails to do anything on subsequent button presses. I had a bit of a poke around, and it seems that after the first append, the "newstuff.innerHTML" is emptied. After much fruitless searching, I decided to come and ask here.

The event handler is firing, the innerHTML of the variable is being appended, but I can't for the life of me work out why my variable is getting trashed.

The variables and data below have been changed to protect the innocent.

```
var button = document.getElementById('add_stuff');
var oldstuff = document.getElementById('element_id');
var newstuff = document.createElement('div');
newstuff.innerHTML = "<p>Super interesting content</p>";
button.onclick = function(event) {
    while (newstuff.firstChild) {
        oldstuff.appendChild(newstuff.firstChild);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because a DOM node can only exist in one place in the DOM.  When you call `lineitems.appendChild(newstuff.firstChild)`, it is removing it from the original place and adding it to the new location.  This means it will only work once.

That being said, this would repeatedly add the markup like you want:

```
button.onclick = function(event) {
    lineitems.innerHTML += newstuff.innerHTML;
};
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/LAKkQ/

Comment: Thanks for the info, however your code locks seems to lock up Chromium.

Comment: I think you may have your variables mixed up or something.  I've tested the code and it works fine in Chrome, see http://jsfiddle.net/LAKkQ/.

Comment: It wasn't the variables, but I'm not quite sure what the problem was.

Either way, I got your method to work. Is there any advantage to this method over the one described below? I prefer this over that the clumsy DOM abstraction layer.

Comment: You mean cloneNode? Nope, I think either way works just as well.

Comment: I've found a caveat; upon concatenation `newstuff`, the values of any form elements in `oldstuff` are scrubbed. If I were to hazard a guess, I'd say JS is fetching the content of both, concatenating them, and replacing `oldstuff` with `oldstuff+newstuff`, rather than truly appending. Am I far off the mark?

Comment: This is because the value of the form elements aren't stored in markup. In that instance cloneNode would do the trick.

Comment: You're correct. Just to clarify for anyone reading this, the problem specifically was the use of the cat/assign (+=) operator versus the use of appendChild.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* `appendChild` will actually *move* `firstChild`, not clone it. To clone it, you can use the [cloneNode](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/cloneNode) method on `firstChild` first, or get the HTML for `firstChild` and then use innerHTML again to append it.