# appendChild from childNodes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

This is an interesting question I saw on the net but didn't know the answer:

The following code is intended to add five identical boxes containing links to the document, but it doesn’t work properly. Why not?

```
// Copies the contents of one box into another
function copyContents(from, to){
    for( var i=0; i<=from.childNodes.length-1; i++){
        to.appendChild(from.childNodes[i]); // <---- Error on this line.
    }
}

//create a box to copy:
var referenceBox = document.createElement('div');

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'http://www.example.com/';
link.textContent = 'A link';

referenceBox.appendChild(link);

//Add box copies to the document
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
    var newBox = document.createElement('div');
    copyContents(referenceBox, newBox);

    document.body.appendChild(newBox);
}
```

**Options**:

1. to.appendChild() expects HTML, but from.childNodes[i] is a node object, so all the boxes will contain the texts[Object Node].
2. document.createElement() reuses existing elements with the same tag, so only one box is added to the document.
3. The same link element can’t have multiple parents,so only one box ends up with a link in it.
4. A link’s href has to be set using setAttribute(); setting the property link.href won’t do anything,so none of the links in the boxes will point anywhere.

I guess the answer is 3, but not sure and don't know why?

Any explanation? Tnx

[link: to the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA51T.png)

Comment: You're not copying but moving. Note that *from.childNodes* is a live collection, so as you move them the length is reducing and you'll only move those that were even indexes to begin with (when you move 0, 1 moves to 0 so when you move 1, it was the previous 2 and so on…).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only iterate from i = 0 to childNodes.length - 1 in `copyContent`. Also, you should [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) DOM nodes if you want to append them to multiple locations in your document (= 3rd option):

```js
// Copies the contents of one box into another:
function copyContents(from, to) {
    for (var i = 0; i < from.childNodes.length; i++) { // <-- change <= to <
        to.appendChild(from.childNodes[i].cloneNode(true)); // <-- add cloneNode(true); to clone node and all its children
    }
}

// Create a box to copy:
var referenceBox = document.createElement('div');

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'http://www.example.com/';
link.textContent = 'A link';

referenceBox.appendChild(link);

// Add box copies to the document:
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var newBox = document.createElement('div');
    copyContents(referenceBox, newBox);

    document.body.appendChild(newBox);
}
```

See also [appendChild only works first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981145/appendchild-only-works-first-time)

Comment: Tnx for the "childNodes.length - 1" fix. However, you can see that the output has only 1 link and not 5 as expected in the question.

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to clone the childnodes of `referenceBox` if you want to copy them to multiple locations in your DOM tree.

Comment: KING. Thanks!, So If I understand you, the answer is 3) "The same link element can’t have multiple parents,so only one box ends up with a link in it."

Comment: Correct. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981145/appendchild-only-works-first-time